# Jenkins - Make pass/fail dependent on results from script command

Tags: jenkins

I'm admittedly very new to using Jenkins, so I apologize if this is something simple I'm overlooking. In my Jenkins job, I have a bash command to run a Python script. Everything runs correctly at the moment, and the Python script works. However, the script can give a pass or fail result after running (to clarify, a fail doesn't mean the script crashed, just that it ran through and, with the variables given, gave the result that with those variables it is wrong). I need to make it so the job fails when the "fail" result is given, but I can't figure out a way to make the Jenkins pass/fail dependent on anything other than whether everything runs properly. How can I set it in such a way that whether the job passes or fails depends on the python script output? Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So from what I could figure out, the easiest way to do this is to modify the Python script so that it exits with a non-zero value when it returns the undesirable value, and with zero otherwise, so the success of the job will mimic the success of the script.

Comment: Or you could use the console-parser plugin. The nice think about this plugin is that you can also make the job unstable. ;)